# How to generate the captcha to train with Python

Tags: python, captcha

I would like to use deep learning program for recognizing the captcha using keras with python.

But the big challenge is to generate massive captcha to train. 
I want to solve a captcha like this
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can i easily generate above massive captcha to train.

Currently, i use python package captcha

```
from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha  # pip install captcha
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import random
import os

number = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
MAX_CAPTCHA = 6
WIDTH=100
HEIGHT=30

image = ImageCaptcha(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, font_sizes=[30])

captcha_text = []
for i in range(MAX_CAPTCHA):
    c = random.choice(number)
    captcha_text.append(c)
    #print(captcha_text)
captcha_text = ''.join(captcha_text)
print(captcha_text)

captcha = image.generate(captcha_text)
captcha_image = Image.open(captcha)
captcha_image = np.array(captcha_image)

image.write(captcha_text, str(i)+'_'+captcha_text + '.png') 
plt.imshow(captcha_image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If it is a web captcha then you can simply run a scraper and download 1000's of captcha from the website. Only if this is case!

Comment: _"Currently, i use python package captcha"_ - so you already have a solution?

Comment: No the trained model to predict real captcha is very pooe

Answer (score 0):

If there is no existing similar captcha datasets online I would tackle this problem in the following way:

1. Get the MNIST dataset
2. Take one image example and play with it in gimp or some image transformation librari like Open CV, to get a look similar to your captcha examples.
3. Transform the MNIST examples in a way you find fit (some random noise, and randomized color on black pixels or something)
4. Train a model on these augmented examples

Now for practical use it depends a little what kind of model you are implementing. If you have a model that can detect and classify all the numbers on the image then you are finished. But if you like to have a simple model that classifies only images with a single digit on them, then you can move a sliding window over your captcha image and only collect outputs of windows for wich the model has high enough confidence that there is some number pressent in the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate captchas using PIL python Imaging Library
Another solution may be using Inkscape and its python scripting api.

There are some program already available using these technologies:
https://github.com/kuszaj/claptcha

https://github.com/ramwin/captcha

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-code-for-generating-an-image-CAPTCHA-using-Python